# Simulate PDF-Overprinting

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I want to simulate Overprinting like in Acrobat Pro, where you can deactivate a single CMYK color and check if the underlaying colors are removed. Without overprinting activated, when you offset-print for example black text on a red background, you may see white borders around the font, because the background is removed under the text.

I have found the following ghostscript command, but it gives me the error "/typecheck in --setcolortransfer--". Is overprinting-simulation even possible with GS?

```
gs -o output.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dOverprint=2 -c "/ColorConversionStrategy /sRGB /ProcessColorModel /DeviceRGB" -c "/DeviceCMYK << /C [0.0] >> setcolortransfer" -f input.pdf
```

Comment: Ghostscript honours overprint, it does not permit you to drop device colours when printing to a composite output. In particular the pdfwrite device doesn't do that (which is what you are using). You could render to a separated output (such as tiffsep) and combine the separate plates yourself. Ghostscript won't do it for you. Your command line won't work. sRGB is not the same as DeviceRGB, and you can't set ColorConversionStrategy to sRGB, only device colours or DeviceIndependentColor. Your PostScript code executing setcolortransfer doesn't make any sense at all I'm afraid, hence the error.

Comment: Also... -dOverprint doesn't take a numeric value, it should be one of /enable, /disable or /simulate. It also has no effect whatsoever with the pdfwrite device. The control is documented here https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/gs10.0.0/Use.html#doverprint-enable-disable-simulate

Comment: @KenS Tiffsep works like a charm, thanks!